# How to embed Magento categories into third party websites

Tags: magento2.4, third-party-plugin

Are there any possibilities to embed Magento categories into third-party websites?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use `V1/categories` API..

Comment: How to do this with API @Pawan

Comment: using CURL, please see my answer.You can just run this script in a simple php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get categories outside Magento by using API endpoints.

```
<?php

    //get Admin token

    $userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "Admin@123");
    $ch = curl_init("http://magento241.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

    $token = curl_exec($ch);

    //get categories
    
    $ch = curl_init("http://magento241.com/index.php/rest/V1/categories");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($result);
```

**Note:**

- You need to change URL of magento
- Create a new Admin user and allow only catalog/category resource(for testing you can use existing admin user)
- Above script is just an example to get category..You need to change according to your third party application..